# what is the exact meaning of パネだく in below sentence

Tags: meaning

I searched in internet to find the meaning of パネだく in the below sentence:

> 世の中には 説明のつかないことがパネだくあっし。

the brief translation I found for this sentence is:

> This world is full of things which are difficult to explain.

But I want to know the exact meaning of パネだく.
In my search, I found the meaning of パネ as Pane and だく(抱く)as to hug, to harbor, to entertain, `to sleep with. As a result, I think the meaning of パネだく may be things that lay on earth or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a combination of these two slang words:

- **パない** = **パねえ** ∼ "extreme; extraordinary". This is yet another recent slangy intensifier coined by abbreviating [半端ない](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8D%8A%E7%AB%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84). See: [「パない」「半端ではない」。辞書にある？](https://dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/column/sankok85)
- **-だく** ∼ "-rich; extra-". This is a suffix that was probably derived from [だくだく](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8F) ("dripping"). The だく suffix was originally an argot used in the gyudon industry (look up つゆだく and ねぎだく), but it's now sometimes used humorously in more general situations.

While パねえ and だく are relatively common by themselves, I haven't seen パネだく before. For now, I think it's more of a one-off play on words, but it's not surprising if it's an adverb used by some fictional character or in a small community somewhere.

あっし is just a contracted version of あるし.

Comment: Thank you very much